# Setting the parameters of an imputer within a three levels pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I'm a newbie in this DataScience realm and in order to organize my code I'm using pipeline.

The snippet of the code I'm trying to organize follows:

```python
### Preprocessing ###
# Preprocessing for numerical data
numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
                ('imputer', SimpleImputer()),
                ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

# Preprocessing for categorical data
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))
])

# Bundle preprocessing for numerical and categorical data
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])

### Model ###
model = XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:squarederror', n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05) 

### Processing ###
# Bundle preprocessing and modeling code in a pipeline
my_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                              ('model', model)
                             ])

parameters = {}
# => How to set the parameters for one of the parts of the numerical_transformer pipeline?

# GridSearch
CV = GridSearchCV(my_pipeline, parameters, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error', n_jobs= 1)

CV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How can I change the parameters for the Imputer found in the numerical_transformer pipeline?

Thank you,

Comment: What are the exact parameters of the imputer you want to tune?

Comment: Hi,

The strategy parameter. I want it to be 'mean', 'median', and 'most_frequent'

I tried something like:  
parameters['preprocessor__numerical_transformer__strategy'] = ['mean', 'median', 'most_frequent']

But it didn't work.

Comment: what about `preprocessor__transformers__cat__imputer__strategy`?

Comment: Why would I change the categorical if I need to change the numerical transformer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were using imputer to both. So, `preprocessor__transformers__num__imputer__strategy`

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't work. 

=> Invalid parameter numerical_transformer

But this seems to be the direction I need to head to...

Comment: This seems to work: parameters['preprocessor__num__imputer__strategy'] = ['most_frequent']

Comment: Cool! Add is an an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @desernaut pointing to the right direction, this is the answer:

```
parameters['preprocessor__num__imputer__strategy'] = ['most_frequent','mean', 'median',]
```

Thanks @desernaut!